# There is vulnerability in our application called Insecure Transport: Weak SSL Protocol how to fix this in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl

There is vulnerability in our application called Insecure Transport: Weak SSL Protocol. After going through StackOverflow I found the solution to fix this vulnerability is that I Need to add

`SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1`

in apache configuration. 
Added that in /extra/httpd-ssl.conf file. I want to know whether this will be called because in the httpd.conf it is commented as below

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.`

Please let me know how to fix the weak SSL protocol issue in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xx.xxxx.com
    ServerName customer.xxxx.com
    ServerAlias origin-customer.xxxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxxx.com
    DocumentRoot "/apps/production/app/apache/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "| /apps/production/app/apache/bin/rotatelogs /apps/production/app/apache/logs/customer.xxxx.com-SSL-error_log.%Y%m%d 86400"
    CustomLog "| /apps/production/app/apache/bin/rotatelogs /apps/production/app/apache/logs/customer.xxxx.com-SSL-access_log-cus.%Y%m%d 86400" combined
    LogLevel warn
Header echo akamai-x-cache-on
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    <Directory "/apps/production/app/apache/htdocs">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
        ErrorDocument 500 https://www.xxxx.com/maintenance/
        ErrorDocument 503 https://www.xxxx.com/maintenance/
        ErrorDocument 404 https://www.xxxx.com/404
        ErrorDocument 403 https://www.xxxx.com/maintenance/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you already had SSL configured before?

Comment: SSL is already configured. I can see that enabled in the httpd.conf as LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so Recently security team found that it is Insecure Transport: Weak SSL Protocol.

Comment: They want to remove Use of a weak protocol such as TLS 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weak SSL protocol generally means that you apache supports obsolete protocols, which do not provide adequate amount of security. The TLS 1.0/1.1 and SSL 2.0/3.0 protocols are outdated with TLS 1.0 is vulnerable to certain attacks. These should not be supported.

To acheive it search your `httpd.conf` or `ssl.conf` file for `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` and comment it.

Add the following line in its place.

`SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1`

This can be done inside your `<VirtualHost>` configuration if you have configured it that way too. To answer your last part of the question if the new SSL configuration file include is commented it will not be included.

[Apache Documentation Link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

Sample configuration using virtual host

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
            RewriteEngine On
            ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/
            ServerName *.domain.com
            SSLEngine on

            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

            SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/certificate.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
            ServerPath /var/
            <Directory "/var/www/">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In httpd.conf there is no SSLProtocol, inside conf/site/ there are 00.ssl.conf and other files which contains <VirtualHost *:8081> and its not 443. This configuration was done long back and untouched. I am not aware of that and no document. That is why I am struggling to fix.

Comment: If your SSLConfiguration is inside `<VirtualHost*:8081>`  You can add `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` in it. Please post the configurations after removing out the confidential data, or else its too broad to answer.

Comment: Added the sample in my question

Comment: The config you added dosen't contain the config the SSL as it should have `SSLCertificateFile` key path etc. It should be configured elsewhere. Please find that out and post the SSL config

Comment: Thanks SIva for your time and help. You are correct. I contacted the team who are into Apache configuration to find the file where the SSL configuration is implemented.

Comment: In the httpd.conf the call to secure SSL is commented out # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: So what is the solution you found?